# Continuity of a characteristic function on the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Here is my problem:

Let $X$ be a metric space and $S \subseteq X$. Then the boundary of $S$ (denoted $\delta S$) is the set of all boundary points of $S$. Let $\chi_S : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be the characteristic function of $S$, defined as: for any $x \in X$, $\chi_S = 1$  if $x \in S$ and $\chi_S = 0$ if $x \notin S$. Show that 
$\chi_S$ is discontinuous at $a \in X$ if and only if $a \in \delta S$.

What I have to work with are some definitions about continuity, like : Let f be a function from a metric space $M_1$ into a metric space $M_2$. Let $a \in M_1$.Then f is continuous at a if and only if whenever $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $M_1$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = a$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) = f(a)$.

I think I will argue by contradiction, but I am not sure how to use these pieces. Any advice?

Comment: Start by writing down the definition of a boundary point, and then think about what it means when a point in $S$ is *not* a boundary point (i.e., an interior point).

Comment: ... In particular, what makes a point an *interior point* of $S$?

Comment: It might help to know that $\partial S= \overline{S}\cap\overline{S^c}$.